# Yammer API - how to get full list of likes using messages endpoint?

Tags: yammer

I've noticed that the messages.json endpoint doesn't seem to return all the data needed to show the likes per message.

Specifically, two things seem to be happening:

1. List of likers only has info on 3 users.
2. The avatar images for the likers is not always available when looking up through the "references" array.

We're using the JS SDK for our integration.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yammer REST API - Message Likes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046312/yammer-rest-api-message-likes)

Answer (score 1):

`https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/liked_message/:Message_id.json` should return user properties of LIKERS, a count of all LIKERS should give you the total LIKES per message.

In practice, you'd need to call the messages endpoint, get the message id, then pass it into users/liked_message/:Message_id.json programatically.

See here for further details - https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersliked_messagemessage_idjson